# Word for point-by-point response

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I saw someone use this word before, but I cannot remember what it is. The word
describes this scenario:

1. Person A makes some points:

   This is 1st point. This is 2nd point. This is 3rd point.
2. Person B refutes those points, often interleaving the original points:

   > This is 1st point.

   1st point is wrong because reasons.

   > This is 2nd point.

   2nd point is wrong because reasons.

   > This is 3rd point.

   3rd point is wrong because reasons.

I remember reading a word or phrase that decribed Person B’s line-by-line
response.

Comment: _Line by line response_ is perfect. And so is _point by point response_

Comment: You could use [*repartee*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/repartee).

Comment: [Stonewalling?](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stonewall)

Comment: “itemized” or “item by item”? “exhaustive”? “all-encompassing”? “thorough”?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## fisk

> To rebut an argument line by line, especially on the Internet.
>
> Named after journalist Robert Fisk. Originated in the blogosphere.

http://wiktionary.org/wiki/fisk#Etymology_2

Answer (score 2):

Blow-by-blow perhaps? Originally referred to detailed accounts in prize-fight broadcasts.

**EDIT**

What you described is a [rebuttal](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rebuttal), or as ab2 pointed out a point-by-point rebuttal.

Comment: Cut and thrust?

Comment: What you described is a [rebuttal](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rebuttal).

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 You might want to add "rebuttal" to your answer--I think it's the right word here.

Comment: +1, but I suggest you edit your answer to "point-by-point rebuttal."  The OP isn't going to get a single word.